# Pyximport build errors

Tags: python, numpy, cython, distutils, mingw-w64

Right now I'm trying to compile and run [Deep Q Learning](https://github.com/spragunr/deep_q_rl). I've got everything set up and working except for one issue related to pyximport.

In [ale_data_set.py](https://github.com/spragunr/deep_q_rl/blob/master/deep_q_rl/ale_data_set.py]), it imports pyximport to compile [shift.pyx](https://github.com/spragunr/deep_q_rl/blob/master/deep_q_rl/shift.pyx). The error I receive:

> **ImportError: Building module shift failed: ['ImportError: DLL load 
>   failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.\n']**

When I run the lines at the top of `ale_data_set.py`, I get the same error:

```
import numpy as np

import pyximport; pyximport.install()

import shift
```

The thing is, sometimes I can get it run import shift just fine. Sometimes I'll be able to `reload(pyximport)`, then call `pyximport.install()` and `import shift` just fine. Other times it doesn't work.

The interesting thing to me is that the times that it doesn't work, when I exit (via control-c), I get this:

```
Exception KeyboardInterrupt in <module 'threading' from 'C:\SciSoft
\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.3\python-2.7.9.amd64\Lib\threading.pyc'> ignored
```

This seems to tell me that it's still compiling in the background, or at least the thread has not returned. It makes sense to me that the sometimes that it works, I just happen to be calling `import shift` after it's finished compiling.

Does anyone know what may be causing this?

If it's just a threading issue, is there a way for me to get the thread from compiling `shift` so I can `wait` it?

Edit: I've also tried setting the numpy `include_dirs` and that has not helped.

I've also checked to make sure there are no spaces in the path, that GCC is in the PATH, and that the MS compiler is also installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm still not sure why it is not importing properly after calling `pyximport`, but I did notice that `shift.pyd` was being created seemingly properly. As such, I took the file (in the build output directory) and copied it over to `*PythonDir*/Lib/site-packages`. I can now just call `import shift` without using `pyximport` and it seems to be working just fine.